# Como fazer app Ionic 6 executando tarefa em segundo plano?

Tags: ionic, vue.js

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo Ionic 6 e esse aplicativo precisa executar uma tarefa em segundo plano.

Encontrei um plugin chamado BackgroundMode mais parece que o mesmo foi descontinuado.

Nesse aplicativo tenho uma funcao socket para comunicar novos alertas mais como ela nao funciona em segundo plano se caso o app nao estiver aberto ela nao funciona, por esse motivo preciso desse BackgroundMode.

Aplicado esta sendo desenvolvido em IONIC6, VUE.

Answer (score -2):

O plugin [Background Mode](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/background-mode/) não parece ter sido [descontinuado](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode). Ele previne o app de hibernar enquanto está em segundo plano. Mas se o app for encerrado, vai encerrar o serviço em background também.

Também existe o plugin [Autostart](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/autostart/), que reinicia o app automaticamente após desligamento e atualização.

Mas o **ideal** para o seu caso seria usar [**NativeScript**](https://v6.docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/ios-runtime/how-to/backgroundexecution) ou [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/) para ter mais acesso às APIs nativas. Com elas você poderá gerenciar os serviços manualmente.

Comment: BackgroundMode me atende bem fechar o aplicativo não é um problema tento em vista que toda vez que o usuário faz login isso gera um registro no backend, na minhas buscar como e nos links que você postou pode observar que a versão do ionic e a 3 na versão 4 o pacote não existe e na 5 ele volta diferente mais na versão 6 também não tem ele mais.

Comment: Experimenta fazer adaptação ao pacote da versão 5 para funcionar na que você usa. Ou então veja se é possível fazer um plugin nativo.

Comment: Pelo que testei ele funciona não muito bem somente ate a versão 8 do Android mais com as novas versões não funciona, tem mais alguma dica que possa me ajudar?